# How to disable the output messages in CPLEX solver?

Tags: python, cplex, pulp

I am using [Pulp modeler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PuLP) with python to solve an integer programming problem. I am using IBM CPLEX as a solver. When I run my Python program, I have a lot of output messages in the console like:

> The CPLEX Optimizers will solve problems up to 1000 variables and 1000 constraints. IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio Preview Edition good for 48 more days ...

I look for a solution on the internet and I fix the issue. So I disable the display by writing `msg=0` as follows:

```
from coinor.pulp import *
# ...
prob = LpProblem("MyProblem", LpMaximize)
# ...
prob.solve(CPLEX(msg=0))
```

Yesterday I removed some softwares from my computer and when I tried to run my Python program, Python says `cannot run cplex.exe`. I find out that something went wrong with my environment variables (all environment variable in path are erased). So I re-installed the CPLEX solver and I run exactly the same program but I still have the output messages now even with `msg=0`.

What do you think is the problem? And how can I disable the output messages?

Comment: Is the new cplex.exe install in your environment path ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe simply redirect stdout of the command to nul? cplex.exe ..your args.. > nul